# How do i get rspec to read the dependencies in my gemspec?

Tags: rspec, gemspecs

When I run 'rspec' or 'bundle exec rspec' it doesn't let me use the dependencies in my .gemspec file.  Do I have to repeat myself and break the DRY principle and display my gems in Gemfile and .gemspec??  (ps. I am doing this for my models files as a rails engine)

Gemfile:

```
gemspec
```

.gemspec:

```
  s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 3.2.13"
  s.add_dependency "mongoid"
  s.add_dependency "mongoid_commentable"
```

Example:

"bundle exec rspec"
Displays errors:

```
uninitialized constant Mongoid::Commentable
uninitialized constant Comment::Mongoid_Commentable
uninitialized constant Mongoid::Commentable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gem dependencies are not autoloaded as opposed to using Bundler/Gemfile. Thus, you'll have to `require` the gems that you depend upon.

Comment: where do you typically autoload these, in spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Usually you load your gem in the spec_helper. Your gem should be loading it's dependencies in its main file.

Comment: You should also think about adding it to the ruby file in gem which the main app loads e.g. if your gem is my_gem you should add the dependency in lib/my_gem.rb file